# Referencing a control from SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I'm using C# to link with an Access database I have. I added this database by using the Data Source Configuration Wizard in VS, and now there are a couple of queries I'm trying to run.

This is the query I'm having trouble with, I think it's having an issue with me trying to reference a combobox from inside the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column2
FROM            MyTable
WHERE           Column1 = cboMyComboBox.Text
ORDER BY        Column2
```

A sample of data in the MyTable

```
Column1     Column2
Male        Bob
Female      Jane
Male        Jim
Male        John
Female      Jill
```

And lets say the value in cboMyComboBox is 'Male'

I'm trying to get the query to return 'Bob', 'Jim' and 'John'

I'm pretty new to this so I'm probably missing something completely obvious, and feel free to refer me to any guides on doing this properly. (It may have something to do with parameters...? Do i need to be passing something to this query?)

The error I'm receiving is "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Comment: What problem do you have with your query.  It looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Just edited with the error - "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Comment: You are using c# to access the db, but you are sending cboMyComboBox.Text in the sql string?  This is not something that would compile.  Perhaps you can post the actual code?

Comment: are you using a parameterized query?

Comment: paqogomez: No i don't think so, and I"m a bit confused on how to do this properly.. I'm adding these queries to a table adapter in VS, is there a way to add parameters through that?

Comment: In the past I have seen this, the issue was the column names have spaces in them. Can you confirm that the columns are 'Column1' and 'Column2'?

Answer (score 1):

```
string query = String.Format(
                 @"SELECT DISTINCT Column2 FROM MyTable 
                   WHERE Column1 = '{0}' ORDER Y Column2", cboMyComboBox.Text);
```

Otherwise the sql query will try and literally match column1 to the string `cboMyComboBox.Text` as opposed to the data in it.

In complete form:

```
public DataTable dattab;
public void GetData()
{
    //setup the parameters for connecting
    string connString = @"";// You need to define you connection string here.
    string query = String.Format(@"SELECT DISTINCT Column2 FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 = '{0}' ORDER Y Column2", cboMyComboBox.Text);

    //Create the connection and commmand objects, then open a connection to the DB.
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);        
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();

    //Retrieve the data and fill the datatable
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dattab);

    //Close off connections
    conn.Close();
    da.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is on the right track - Do you know how to do this with a tableadapter query?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - In the query properties there is an option to add parameters - I was able to add it here then pass the combobox value when i ran the query method:

```
tableAdapter.GetColumn1Data(cboMyComboBox.Text)
```

[image: Table Adapter]